# How can i combine a list of float values into one character?

Tags: c, character

So im new to c and i am trying to combine a list of float values into a character and am unsure of what to do, ive tried using && as follows:

```
*message = "%f %f %f %f %f %f\n" && val1 && val2 && val3 && val4 && val5 && val6;
printf("%f\n" message);
```

But the print comes out corrupted. ive also tried this using comma separation:

```
*message = "%f %f %f %f %f %f\n", val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6;
printf("%f\n" message);
```

but it says that this adds it to an array which isnt what i need.

Is there any way to combine float values into a character as ive done above?

Comment: Use `sprintf` if you want the string in memory. In the second attempt, replace `*message = ...;` with `printf( ... );` if you just want the numbers printed.

Comment: is there anyway of storing that string into a variable? - just realised what i said thanks for the help my man

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a formatted string when declaring the variable, you need to use the `sprintf()` function to format it.

```
#define MAXMESSAGE 100
char message[MAXMESSAGE];
sprintf(message, "%f %f %f %f %f %f", val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6);
printf("%s\n", message);
```